# Want to search for a specific user in different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Suppose we have multiple databases on the same server. I want to search for a specific user using single query, without selecting the database. I just wanted to know which database a specific user belongs to. Is it possible?

Comment: "Search a specific user" -- a SQL Server account, or a row in a "user" table?  Clarify.

Comment: see i have multiple databases in which i store all details about user. now the scenarios is some time we got the request from user that time i am having only user information like name and last name, email id. now what i want i need to search the user from all the databases present on the same server.the user belongs to which database.

Comment: Then you need a stored procedure that can iterate over all your different databases.  It will work but this is a poor design if you ever have to migrate databases or add new ones.  If the same user name is used in two databases -- you're screwed.

Comment: thaks bro that means pratically it is not possible right

Comment: Providing you keep the users information aligned then this shouldn't be a problem. You could use dynamic SQL to iterate over existing databases therefore allowing for new ones to be implemented and not breaking this feature. You could build up a Temp table and yes you could see that the corresponding user belongs to the corresponding database.

Comment: Possible, but not maintainable over the long term.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
declare @dbs varchar(500),
        @db int,
        @dbname varchar(500),
        @sql nvarchar(500),
        @username varchar(500)
declare C cursor for select name from sysdatabases
open C
fetch C into @dbname
set @dbs = ''
set @username = '<the user you are looking for>'
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @sql = N'select @db=count(*) from  ' + @dbname + '.dbo.sysusers where name = ''' + @username + ''''
    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@db int output', @db output
    if @db > 0
        set @dbs = @dbs + @dbname + ', '
    fetch C into @dbname
end
close C
deallocate C
select @dbs
```

I gives you a comma separated list of all databases where the user looking for exists.
After that you can adopt this query as it fits, it's just a hint.

Comment: This is susceptible to SQL Injection, all user input should be parameterised.

Comment: Well, I do not see here any user input :-) This is an old good TSQL run out of SSMS. Where should SQL Injection come from?